# Make gradient look the same on different screens

Tags: android, android-studio, radial-gradients, android-shape, android-shapedrawable

I have defined gradient drawable for my app's navigation drawer's header,

**side_nav_bar.xml:**

```
<gradient
        android:centerColor="@color/ColorTwoBackground"
        android:endColor="@color/ColorTwoForeground"
        android:gradientRadius="400"
        android:startColor="@color/ColorTwoBackground"
        android:type="radial" >
</gradient>
```

However, it looks as intended only on some devices. On other devices it looks bad.

[image: first image]

[image: second image]

[image: third image]

As you can see in the last image logo loses its contrast...

I want to change it to appear identical or even closely the same on different screens. Probably **gradientRadius** value does the biggest impact but I have tried other values and **"400"** seemed to be optimal. Maybe it is possible to determine it programmatically?

Comment: `android:gradientRadius="400"` use `dp`, for example `100dp`

Comment: @pskink dp gives me all white background. I have tried different radius values (0dp - 1000dp) but it didn't give effect I want

Comment: so `android:gradientRadius="400"` works but `android:gradientRadius="100dp"` doesn't? strange... you can also try `%`, for example  `75%`

Comment: @pskink any dp value gives me white background: http://imgur.com/BjOZ2mu
"%" gives some background but not as intended

Comment: [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=71065) the same behavior is described

Comment: changing xml file did not work, but adding it programmatically improved the situation. @pskink Thanks for your efforts

Comment: sure,  no problem